# Is this what is meant by quadratic equation , function?

Tags: quadratics

It says in my textbook that :

> Let $f(x) - g(x) = 0$. Then, let this equation be $h(x)$.
> If $h(x)$ is a quadratic Q.F, then $h(x) = 0$ is a quadratic equation.

I need to ask some questions regarding this statement i.e.

$1)$ When I say $f(x)-g(x) = 0$. So, is this statement an equation? And $f(x) - g(x)$ is a function until there is no equal to sign?

$2)$ Why did we equate  $f(x)-g(x)$  to $h(x)$ and then call $h(x)$ as a quadratic function?

$3)$ When I say $h(x) = 0$ is a quadratic equation, there is still a function ${ h(x) }$ which we wrote. Shouldn’t we write the value of $h(x)$ (Let it be for example $2x^2 +x+4$) and then call it a quadratic equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a strange phrasing to me.

I would say let $f(x)-g(x)$ be $h(x)$. If $h(x)$ is a quadratic function, then $h(x)=0$ is a quadratic equation.

1. Yes, it is an equation.  $f(x)-g(x)$ is a function of $x$.
2. We don't just call it a quadratic function, we have to verify that.
3. When we mention quadratic equation, we should see the equal sign somewhere.

Comment: So , there is no significance of writing f(x) - g(x) = h(x) and then call it a Q.F . You see , what I mean is that it is not Sth universal right.

Comment: Also , why didn’t you write h(x) = 0 but wrote q(x) = 0?

Comment: I typed wrongly, I meant to type $h(x)=0$.

Comment: 1st comment ? . . .

Comment: For example, for $f(x)=x^3+x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3$, then $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ is a quadratic function. I don't think it is significant.

Comment: Ohk. Thanks a lot for helping me out.Hope you have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

$1)$ $f(x)-g(x)=0$ is an equation. $ f(x)-g(x)$ is a function.

$2)$ $h(x)$ being equal to an *equation* makes no sense. If your book says instead that $h(x) =f(x)-g(x)$, then $h(x)$ is really no quadratic function. It is the zero function. The degree of a quadratic is $2$, whereas the degree of the zero function is undefined. I believe this answers $(3)$ as well.